# Changing text inside a tag onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the text when clicking on a button.
The button was created with a div :

```
<nav class="retour white"><a href="photos.html">Retour</a></nav>

<div class="pause" id="pause" onclick="playpause()"><a href="#">Pause</a></div>
<video autoplay id="bgvid" loop>
    <source src="videos/chat/chat_noir.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

My function :

```
function playpause(){

    var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
    var pauseText = document.getElementById("pause");

    if (video.paused){
        video.play();
        pauseText.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        video.pause();
        pauseText.innerHTML = "Jouer";
    }

}
```

My CSS :

```
 .retour{
width:100%;
height: 50px;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
z-index: 2;
top: 0px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.retour a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
padding:14px;
display:inline-block;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/****** VIDEOS  ******/

video { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url('') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
transition: 1s opacity;
}

.white{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6) !important;
}
.pause{
width:80px;
height: 50px;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
z-index: 2;
top: 0px;
right:0px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
}
.pause a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
padding:14px;
display:inline-block;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

So I'm able to change the text, but it's removing the `a` tag and removing my style. I tried to add

```
document.getElementById("pause").getElementsByTagName("a")
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show the rest of the relevant HTML.

Comment: The hyperlink is inside of `pause`, therefore when you change the `innerHTML` of `pause` you are removing the hyperlink. Give the id of `pause` to the hyperlink or put the hyperlink outside of the `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
<div class="pause" id="pause" onclick="playpause()"><a href="#">Pause</a></div>
```

Because you have this, the link dissapears when you set the `innerHTML` of the `div` later.

To correct your issue and keep the `a` from dissapearing, you need to get the right DOM reference to it:

```
 var anchor= document.querySelector("#pause > a");
```

Next, don't use inline HTML event handlers as they create spaghetti code and cause global event handling wrapper functions around your event code. These wrappers change the binding of `this` if used by your code.

Here's how to connect to an event handler that uses the W3C DOM Standard:

```
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
     var pauseText = document.getElementById("pause");
     var anchor= document.querySelector("#pause > a");

     pauseText.addEventListener("click", function(){

        if (video.paused){
          video.play();
          anchor.innerHTML = "Pause";
        } else {
          video.pause();
          anchor.innerHTML = "Jouer";
        }

     });
 });
```

> Amd, note the `div` code I showed at the top - - it no longer has the
>   `onclick="playPasue()` in it.

Comment: I added more of my code. I have an a tag inside my div to make sure the text is vertically align inside my div with top: 50% and transform translate.

I got it work with `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];` Not sure if it's a good solution if I change some stuffs in my HTML.

Comment: You should show ALL the relevant code please (including CSS), so we don't have to guess at your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firstElementChild` of `pause` element. I guess problem is a tag is removed

> So I'm able to change the text, but it's removing the a tag and removing my style

```
function playpause(){

var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var pauseText = document.getElementById("pause").firstElementChild;

if (video.paused){
    video.play();
    pauseText.innerHTML = "Pause";
} else {
    video.pause();
    pauseText.innerHTML = "Jouer";
}

}
```

Comment: Nic727 : "So I'm able to change the text, but it's removing the a tag and removing my style." 

Problem is it removes tag

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(){

  var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
  var pauseText = document.querySelector("#pause a");

  if (video.paused){
      video.play();
      pauseText.innerHTML = "Pause";
  }else{
      video.pause();
      pauseText.innerHTML = "Jouer";
  }


}
```

```html
<!-- Got video from http://www.w3schools.com/ -->
<video width="400" id="bgvid">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<div class="pause" id="pause"><a href="#">Pause</a></div>
```

Comment: Event handlers as JavaScript object properties should be avoided as they do not follow the W3C DOM Event Model Standard and don't allow for multiple event handlers registered to a single event. In addition, your code will fail if it is not inside of a `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` event handler. Also, the selector `#pause a` will work, but is not as efficient as `#pause > a`.

Answer (score -3):

You must use it:

```js
function playpause() {
    document.getElementById("pause").innerHTML = "Jouer";
}
```

```html
<div class="pause" id="pause" onclick="playpause()"><a href="#">Pause</a></div>
```