# How to change text of an <a> once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, anchor

I have this custom anchor button on my WordPress website:

```
 <a class="add-to-cart-button">Buy Now</a>
```

I'd like it to change its text on click event. Is it possible to do with javascript/php?

Comment: Not with php, php is server side.  It's important for you to research  the differences there.

Comment: Yes it's possible with javascript, look at adding an event listener for the click event, and innerText

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text inside a tag onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045076/changing-text-inside-a-tag-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the innerHTML via JavaScript after the click

with jQuery:

```
$(".add-to-cart-button").click(function () {
  $(this).html('New Text');
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, this seems to work great. Is it possible to assign a class to the after click version of the button, so that I could add an icon via css's content command?

Comment: Yes, inside the function you can add another line like this: $(this).addClass( "newclass");

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. This is so nifty and I can't believe tit was so easy to accomplish, I really need to start learning jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is quite trivial with some JavaScript. I'm going to assume that you're using an e-commerce plugin and that there's the possibility there may be more than one button on the page. You can just get a nodeList of all the buttons and loop through it, adding an `onclick` function to each one. You don't need jQuery for this specifically.

Take the following snippet:

```js
let addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart-button');

for( i = 0, n = addButtons.length; i < n; ++i ){
  addButtons[i].onclick = function(){
    this.innerText = 'Thanks for buying!';
    this.classList.add( 'purchased' );
  };
}
```

```css
.add-to-cart-button{background:#0095ee;padding:10px 20px;color:#fff;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none}
.purchased { background: #ee3d96; }
.purchased:after { content: ""; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart-button">Buy Now</a>

<a href="#" class="add-to-cart-button">Buy Now</a>

<a href="#" class="add-to-cart-button">Buy Now</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! You made all the correct assumptions, thanks for that as well. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, however. The jQuery Dylan provided below seem to work just fine. Should I stick to that, or is it better to do this function with javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded already, it's perfectly fine to use - but it's not worth the overhead if you're just changing some text and *don't* have it loaded. One thing I would change with his code is to replace `$(this).html('New Text');` with `$(this).text('New Text');` unless you're actually dropping in html - otherwise you should be good to go

Comment: Kind man! Thank you for the explanation. Changed html to text :)

Comment: My pleasure! I also see you were asking @Dylan about adding a class - I've updated my answer to also include that functionality with `this.classList.add( 'purchased' );`. Cheers!

Comment: I'll definitely explore this in the future. I'm still not sure why the javascript didn't work, maybe it has to do with the stupid buttons I'm using. I'm using custom pages to make product pages with woocommerce shortcodes, which has proven to be a mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, click event handler

```
 javascript =>
 document.getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart-button").innerHTML =
 'Text you want';

 jQUery => $('.add-to-cart-button').html('Text you want');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This isn't quite what I want tho - it changes the text of the button altogether. Rather, I'd like it to change the text only after it's clicked on.